# Controlling the PWM module on my PIC16F1575

Tags: c, embedded, pic

I'm lost on how to control the PWM signal on my PIC microcontroller as most guides online seem to include a CCP module and my system does not.

```c
#include "config.h"

#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000

//short pwmModule = PWM1CONbits.OUT; //Global variable for pin select
    
void main( void ){
    
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Oscillator Register">
        //Configure the oscillator block(16MHz)
    OSCCONbits.SPLLEN = 0b0;  //ignored due to config
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b1111; //16MHz
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0b00; //sets clock determined by config
    OSCTUNEbits.TUN = 0b000000; //sets factory calibrated oscillator 
    
    // </editor-fold>
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="PWM Register">
 
    PWM1CONbits.EN = 0b1; //enable PWM bit
    PWM1CONbits.POL = 0b0; //polarity not inverted
    PWM1CONbits.MODE = 0b00; //standard mode
    PWM1CONbits.OE = 0b1; //
    
    PWM1CLKCONbits.PS = 0b001; //divide clock by 2 for source pwm 16M/2
    PWM1CLKCONbits.CS = 0b01; //use high frequency internal oscillator
    
    PWM1OFCONbits.OFM = 0b00; //independant run mode 
    
    
    
    
    // </editor-fold>
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="I/O Configurations">
    //Configure the pins as output
    TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0;
    TRISCbits.TRISC1 = 0;
    TRISAbits.TRISA4 = 0;
    TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 0;

    
    //Clear the output pins    
    LATCbits.LATC0 = 0;
    LATCbits.LATC1 = 0;
    LATAbits.LATA4 = 0;
    LATAbits.LATA5 = 0;

    
    //Configure the pins as input
    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1;
    
    //Configure the inputs pins as digital
    ANSELAbits.ANSA2 = 0;    
    // </editor-fold>
    

    while(1){
        
        LATCbits.LATC0 = PWM1CONbits.OUT;
       
        
    }
    
    
    
    return;
}
```

I wrote this program and have tried measuring the output just to see if there's any PWM coming out at all, but unfortunately there is not.

Comment: There are some PWM examples in the datasheet. Reader about the PWM duty register.

Comment: PIC16F1575 does not look like a beginner friendly chip. I'd suggest you to switch to one of the simpler ones like PIC16F-628A / 631 / 690 / 87 / 88 .. etc. if possible.

Comment: Kozmotronik, is it possible to output the CCP module onto 4 different pins?

Comment: I've warned you about that PIC16F1575 is not a beginner friendly microcontroller. However, since you still insist, then I will try to you an example of how to setup the PWM module based on the datasheet. But you are encouraged to test it in your hardware since I don't have of this chip.

Answer (score 0):

The PIC16F1575 is relatively a new model and is not a common education material.
That's why is your struggle to find some appropriate tutorials for it.

The difference in this model is that it does not have a bundled
CCP (Capture Compare PWM) hardware but only PWM hardware. Not only that,
its PWM hardware has a little different structure compared to the classic
models.

I know that reading datasheets can be challenging but I recommend you
to have a look at your device's [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40001782C.pdf), at least only the sections you
need such as PWM, GPIO and PPS.

Well here is a honorable mention: There is a tool called MCC
(Mplab Code Configurator) that Microchip provides to the developer so that they configure lots of supported PIC models visually and generate driver codes for
hardware. You could make use of this tool to speed up development process and
make things easier. However I would recommend you to see the related sections
in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40001782C.pdf) to see how things go at the hardware level.

Well below is a sample code which I haven't tested and encourage you to do it
since you have the real hardware. Consider it as a sample to start up your
project not as a whole project.

So according to the datasheet there 4 independent PWM modules which can operate
either independently or dependently or by providing some trigger sources.
But here we will use them as independent PWM. Below is a table that shows how each PWM module is configured and what you should see on each pin:

| No | Output Pin | Frequency | Duty Cycle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PWM1 | PORTC0 | 100Hz | %40 |
| PWM2 | PORTC1 | 200Hz | %50 |
| PWM3 | PORTC2 | 500Hz | %60 |
| PWM4 | PORTC3 | 1KHz | %70 |

```c
void OSCILLATOR_Initialize(void) {
    // SCS INTOSC; SPLLEN disabled; IRCF 16MHz_HF; 
    OSCCON = 0x7A;
    // TUN 0; 
    OSCTUNE = 0x00;
    // SBOREN disabled; BORFS disabled; 
    BORCON = 0x00;
}

void PIN_MANAGER_Initialize(void) {
    /**
    LATx registers
    */
    LATA = 0x00;
    LATC = 0x00;

    /**
    TRISx registers
    */
    TRISA = 0x3F;
    TRISC = 0x30;

    /**
    ANSELx registers
    */
    ANSELC = 0x00;
    ANSELA = 0x17;

    /**
    WPUx registers
    */
    WPUA = 0x00;
    WPUC = 0x00;
    OPTION_REGbits.nWPUEN = 1;

    /**
    ODx registers
    */
    ODCONA = 0x00;
    ODCONC = 0x00;

    /**
    SLRCONx registers
    */
    SLRCONA = 0x37;
    SLRCONC = 0x3F;

    /**
    INLVLx registers
    */
    INLVLA = 0x3F;
    INLVLC = 0x3F;
    
    RC0PPS = 0x03;   //RC0->PWM1:PWM1OUT;    
    RC3PPS = 0x06;   //RC3->PWM4:PWM4OUT;    
    RC1PPS = 0x04;   //RC1->PWM2:PWM2OUT;    
    RC2PPS = 0x05;   //RC2->PWM3:PWM3OUT;    
}

void PWM1_Initialize(void) {
    // set the PWM1 to the options selected in the User Interface

     //PHIE disabled; DCIE disabled; OFIE disabled; PRIE disabled; 
    PWM1INTE = 0x00;

     //PHIF cleared; OFIF cleared; DCIF cleared; PRIF cleared; 
    PWM1INTF = 0x00;

     //PS Divide_clock_src_by_4; CS HFINTOSC; 
    PWM1CLKCON = 0x21;

     //LDS LD1_trigger; LDT disabled; LDA do_not_load; 
    PWM1LDCON = 0x00;

     //OFM independent_run; OFS OF1_match; OFO match_incrementing; 
    PWM1OFCON = 0x00;

     //PWM1PHH 0; 
    PWM1PHH = 0x00;

     //PWM1PHL 0; 
    PWM1PHL = 0x00;

     //PWM1DCH 62; 
    PWM1DCH = 0x3E;

     //PWM1DCL 127; 
    PWM1DCL = 0x7F;

     //PWM1PRH 156; 
    PWM1PRH = 0x9C;

     //PWM1PRL 63; 
    PWM1PRL = 0x3F;

     //PWM1OFH 0; 
    PWM1OFH = 0x00;

     //PWM1OFL 7; 
    PWM1OFL = 0x07;

     //PWM1TMRH 0; 
    PWM1TMRH = 0x00;

     //PWM1TMRL 0; 
    PWM1TMRL = 0x00;

     //MODE standard_PWM; POL active_hi; EN enabled; 
    PWM1CON = 0x80;
}

void PWM2_Initialize(void) {
    // set the PWM2 to the options selected in the User Interface

     //PHIE disabled; DCIE disabled; OFIE disabled; PRIE disabled; 
    PWM2INTE = 0x00;

     //PHIF cleared; OFIF cleared; DCIF cleared; PRIF cleared; 
    PWM2INTF = 0x00;

     //PS Divide_clock_src_by_4; CS FOSC; 
    PWM2CLKCON = 0x20;

     //LDS LD1_trigger; LDT disabled; LDA do_not_load; 
    PWM2LDCON = 0x00;

     //OFM independent_run; OFS OF1_match; OFO match_incrementing; 
    PWM2OFCON = 0x00;

     //PWM2PHH 0; 
    PWM2PHH = 0x00;

     //PWM2PHL 0; 
    PWM2PHL = 0x00;

     //PWM2DCH 39; 
    PWM2DCH = 0x27;

     //PWM2DCL 15; 
    PWM2DCL = 0x0F;

     //PWM2PRH 78; 
    PWM2PRH = 0x4E;

     //PWM2PRL 31; 
    PWM2PRL = 0x1F;

     //PWM2OFH 0; 
    PWM2OFH = 0x00;

     //PWM2OFL 7; 
    PWM2OFL = 0x07;

     //PWM2TMRH 0; 
    PWM2TMRH = 0x00;

     //PWM2TMRL 0; 
    PWM2TMRL = 0x00;

     //MODE standard_PWM; POL active_hi; EN enabled; 
    PWM2CON = 0x80;
}

void PWM3_Initialize(void) {
    // set the PWM3 to the options selected in the User Interface

     //PHIE disabled; DCIE disabled; OFIE disabled; PRIE disabled; 
    PWM3INTE = 0x00;

     //PHIF cleared; OFIF cleared; DCIF cleared; PRIF cleared; 
    PWM3INTF = 0x00;

     //PS Divide_clock_src_by_4; CS HFINTOSC; 
    PWM3CLKCON = 0x21;

     //LDS LD1_trigger; LDT disabled; LDA do_not_load; 
    PWM3LDCON = 0x00;

     //OFM independent_run; OFS OF1_match; OFO match_incrementing; 
    PWM3OFCON = 0x00;

     //PWM3PHH 0; 
    PWM3PHH = 0x00;

     //PWM3PHL 0; 
    PWM3PHL = 0x00;

     //PWM3DCH 18; 
    PWM3DCH = 0x12;

     //PWM3DCL 192; 
    PWM3DCL = 0xC0;

     //PWM3PRH 31; 
    PWM3PRH = 0x1F;

     //PWM3PRL 64; 
    PWM3PRL = 0x40;

     //PWM3OFH 0; 
    PWM3OFH = 0x00;

     //PWM3OFL 7; 
    PWM3OFL = 0x07;

     //PWM3TMRH 0; 
    PWM3TMRH = 0x00;

     //PWM3TMRL 0; 
    PWM3TMRL = 0x00;

     //MODE standard_PWM; POL active_hi; EN enabled; 
    PWM3CON = 0x80;
}

void PWM4_Initialize(void) {
    // set the PWM4 to the options selected in the User Interface

     //PHIE disabled; DCIE disabled; OFIE disabled; PRIE disabled; 
    PWM4INTE = 0x00;

     //PHIF cleared; OFIF cleared; DCIF cleared; PRIF cleared; 
    PWM4INTF = 0x00;

     //PS Divide_clock_src_by_4; CS HFINTOSC; 
    PWM4CLKCON = 0x21;

     //LDS LD1_trigger; LDT disabled; LDA do_not_load; 
    PWM4LDCON = 0x00;

     //OFM independent_run; OFS OF1_match; OFO match_incrementing; 
    PWM4OFCON = 0x00;

     //PWM4PHH 0; 
    PWM4PHH = 0x00;

     //PWM4PHL 0; 
    PWM4PHL = 0x00;

     //PWM4DCH 10; 
    PWM4DCH = 0x0A;

     //PWM4DCL 240; 
    PWM4DCL = 0xF0;

     //PWM4PRH 15; 
    PWM4PRH = 0x0F;

     //PWM4PRL 160; 
    PWM4PRL = 0xA0;

     //PWM4OFH 0; 
    PWM4OFH = 0x00;

     //PWM4OFL 7; 
    PWM4OFL = 0x07;

     //PWM4TMRH 0; 
    PWM4TMRH = 0x00;

     //PWM4TMRL 0; 
    PWM4TMRL = 0x00;

     //MODE standard_PWM; POL active_hi; EN enabled; 
    PWM4CON = 0x80;
}

void SYSTEM_Initialize(void) {
    PIN_MANAGER_Initialize();
    OSCILLATOR_Initialize();
    WDT_Initialize();
    PWM1_Initialize();
    PWM2_Initialize();
    PWM4_Initialize();
    PWM3_Initialize();
}

void main(void) {
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    while(1) {
        // Add your application code
    }
}
```